# SVN commit messages of a particular issue in JIRA

Tags: svn, jira-rest-api, atlassian-crucible

I have to fetch the SVN commit messages of a particular issue of JIRA.(https://jira2.####.com/browse/ABCD-1234)

issue key is= ABCD-1234

Can I get some help of API or any link or any method regarding how to fetch the commit messages?

Any Crucible/JIRA/SVN API will be helpful in this case.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Run the [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) command with the [`--search`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search) and [`--search-and`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search_and) arguments. For example, run the following command when you need to view the commits that reference issue PROJECT-1234:

`svn log --search PROJECT-1234 https://svn.example.com/MyRepo/MyProject`